# verify method call for generic method with expression

Tags: c#, moq

I have an interface `IBackgroundJobClient` which has an extension method `Enqueue`

```
 void Enqueue<T>(this IBackgroundJobClient client, Expression<Action<T>> action);
```

and I call it like below

```
 void schedule(int id) 
{

     _job.Enqueue<FileUploadService>(x => x.UploadFile(id));
 }
```

using `Moq` I am trying to verify if Enqueue is called

```
  private Mock<IBackgroundJobClient> _jobClient =  new Mock<IBackgroundJobClient>();
```

and in the test I am trying to verify that its called once

```
 schedule();
 _jobClient.Verify(x => x.Enqueue(It.IsAny<Expression<Action<FileUploadService>>>()), Times.Once);
```

below is the error I am getting

> System.NotSupportedException : Invalid verify on an extension method:
>   x =>
>   x.Enqueue(It.IsAny>>())
>   at
>   Moq.Mock.ThrowIfVerifyExpressionInvolvesUnsupportedMember(Expression
>   verify, MethodInfo method) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line
>   780

How can I verify if method was called once

Comment: Moq does not work with extension methods. There are already many questions here that already establish that

Comment: so then, how do I verify it? I cant?